# Ehcache: Once configured what cache replication algorithm is followed?

Tags: algorithm, logic, replication, ehcache

I am looking for replicating cache. I had gone through the manuals of Ehcache. It only guides about configuration. I need to understand replication from performance prospective.

- Which node will go first in replication?
- What if two peers start caching at the same time?
- In a write extensive application, how ehcache manages the synchronization?
- Which strategy is better JMS, RMI or JGroup.

Answer (score 1):

There is no synchronization in replicated setups. Replication is inherently racy (to your point #2 & #3). You shouldn't make any assumption on what node the replication will *go* first, but probably which it firsts *get* to. That may help answering question #4.

If you want some guarantees around consistency, you should probably cluster your Cache with Terracotta instead.

Comment: As per Ehcahe doc. Replicated – The cached data set is held in each application node and data is copied or invalidated across the cluster without locking. Replication can be either asynchronous or synchronous, where the writing thread blocks while propagation occurs. The only consistency mode available in this topology is Weak Consistency. nodes can be run with open-source Ehcache.

Comment: ... yes. Exactly what I said. The blocking in synchronous mode, isn't blocking threads on other nodes, but only on the emitting one... i.e. there is _no across node synchronization_